# Rails Logger and choosing what to list and what not to list

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a particular chunk of data that is stored in Postgres which involves a name and a mapped set of elements in JSON.  Some of these JSON docs can get quite large.  This causes the log to swell when this data is created(via activerecord save) inside of our rails app.  Is it possible to have the logger ignore this particular field's output (or shorten it to n length)?

The log shows

```
insert... LARGE_JSON_STRING
```

and I would like it to show

```
insert... SMALL_JSON_STRING...
```

Is this possible without monkey patching activerecord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [13.1 Parameters Filtering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters-filtering).

```
# application.rb
config.filter_parameters << :param
```

Comment: Of course, it would be right there in my face and I'd look right over it.  Thanks.